# How to get record id submission in elementor form (using shortcode)

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, elementor

I'm trying to get id submission (shortcode) in elementor form and send it via email

```
<p>Terimakasih telah melakukan registrasi</p>
<p>ID : [?????]</p>
<p>Name : [field id="name"]</p>
```

Does anyone know the shortcode or how to get it? I try to search everywhere but couldn't get the answer.

Comment: Here is your answer: https://elementor.com/help/sending-email-confirmations-with-elementor-forms/

Comment: I didn't see what I looking for